# Authenticate user based on telephone number

Tags: customer-account, validation

I'm trying to validate customers login based on their telephone number and password instead on email and password.

I've rewritten authenticate method of `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` model and the method goes like

```
    /* Load customer collection and filter based on given telephone number. 
Later I'll pass telephone number in parameter. Right now I'm checking for a static telephone number */

  public function authenticate($login, $password)
{
         $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                      ->addNameToSelect()->addAttributeToSelect('email')
                       ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('billing_telephone', '8880421789');

            $login = array();
            foreach($collection as $collection)
            {
                   $login[] = $collection->getData('email');

            }
  $this->loadByEmail($login[0]);
  //Default Magento code goes afterwards          
 if ($this->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired()) {
 throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed.'), self::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED
                        );
                    }
if (!$this->validatePassword($password)) {
throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid login or password.'), self::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD
                        );
                    }
Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_customer_authenticated', array(
                        'model' => $this,
                        'password' => $password,
                    ));
                    return true;
                } }
```

It doesn't validate properly and always throws error "Invalid login or password." . 
*Also is there a proper way to load customer email id using the given telephone number without using collection?.*

Comment: are you sure the correct value is set in `$password`?

Comment: @Sander: Yes, value in password field is correct.

Comment: The `validatePassword` method doesn't use the username for validation so it purely focuses on the given password. Does the code work when you fall back to the original file? Also, are you sure `$this->loadByEmail($login[0]);` actually loads the correct user?

Comment: If I use original authenticate method, it works. I'm getting correct email id in `$login[0]` variable though I'm not sure about `$this->loadByEmail($login[0]);`. How I can debug it?

Comment: If you print `$this->getEmail()` after loading it should return the correct email. That way you can check if Magento loaded the customer into the model

Comment: `print_r($this->getEmail());` has printed correct email id associated with the given telephone number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25072/discussion-between-amitshree-and-sander-mangel).